# How to pad on extra rows in dataframe for Neural Netowrk

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Name | Score | Ind1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 1 |
| A | 31 | 3 |
| B | 40 | 2 |
| B | 33 | 3 |
| B | 20 | 1 |
| B | 33 | 2 |
| C | 21 | 5 |

For each unique name, I want to ensure there are exactly 2 entries. If a name has more than 2 entries, I want the two entries with the largest Score (in case of a tie, just take any two rows with the largest score). If a name has fewer than 2 entries, insert / impute a row for that Name where the Score and Ind1 are both set to 0.

So one possible output for the above table would be:

| Name | Score | Ind1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 1 |
| A | 31 | 3 |
| B | 40 | 2 |
| B | 33 | 3 |
| C | 21 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 0 |

I've thought about doing some weird looping on each row with a groupby(?) for each name, but the groupby makes it hard to count how many rows there are for each Name, and my dataframe is quite large so I'd rather not loop if I don't have to.

Any idea how to do this without looping through each row?

Answer (score 3):

A little hard than I though

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Score'],ascending=[True,False])
#sort_value first 
df = df.groupby('Name').head(2)
#get the top two row per group by Score
df['id'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
#get the unique count per group name , then we fill it up 
out = df.set_index(['Name','id'])\
           .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Name.unique(),df.id.unique()],names=['name','id']))\
              .fillna(0).reset_index().drop('id',1)
out
Out[273]: 
  name  Score  Ind1
0    A   34.0   1.0
1    A   31.0   3.0
2    B   40.0   2.0
3    B   33.0   3.0
4    C   21.0   5.0
5    C    0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Not even sure you need the `head` as the `reindex` should take care of the 2 rows per id anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Drop duplicates from initial df

```
g=df.groupby('Name').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Extract unique values in Name into a list

```
l=list(set(df['Name'].to_list()))
```

Create new Series

```
s=pd.Series(list(np.repeat(l, 2)), name='Name')
```

Merge Series to df

```
g.merge(s.rename('new_Name'), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right').fillna(0).drop('Name',1)



    Score  Ind1 new_Name
0   34.0   1.0        A
1   31.0   3.0        A
2   40.0   2.0        B
3   33.0   3.0        B
4   21.0   5.0        C
5    0.0   0.0        C
```

Comment: Please see my edits. I initially had forgotten to include first step

Comment: What if I had an extra column in my df called "Age" that gives a numerical age value of each Name? I'd like to keep age consistent for each Name, regardless of whether a row was inserted. If C had an age of 50, for example, then both rows for C would have a value of 50 in the age column.